# How can I configure Wso2 Integration Studio API to have access through two different ports simultaneously?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

I have WSO2 Integration Studio API and I need that have a connection by two ports, the first one is through the default port ¨8290¨ and the second one I need that through ¨8291¨

I tried to configure the ¨deployment.toml¨file to change the default port to ¨8281¨ through the next sentence:

```
[server]
hostname = "localhost"
offset = 1
```

but with this sentence I only one can change the default port by 8281 and I need to have access through the 8281 and 8282 ports because I need access to two APIs in the same project at the same time, someone can explain to me how to make this, I will be grateful.

Comment: Do you want to start two servers one on port `8290` and another on port `8291`?

Comment: Yes¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡

Comment: how do i can make it?  ssrr for my english, is very bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `IntegrationStudio/runtime` and make two copies of the folder `microesb`. Lets call these two directories `microesb1` and `microesb2`. Now go to `microesb1/bin` directory and run `sh micro-integrator.sh` this will start a server on the default port `8290`.

Then open `microesb2/conf/deployment.toml` and add the following.

```
[server]
hostname = "localhost"
offset  = 1
```

Now go to `microesb2/bin` directory and run `sh micro-integrator.sh` this will start a server on the default port `8291`

Comment: ok i sucesul, but now how can make a port redirection to one context and than other port redirect to another context? i have a api that show ¨Hello World¨ trought an context named /HelloWorld", is possible have another context for access he trought he and the same time by port 8291?

Comment: thanks for help me, thanks to your indications can redirection my service to two or more ports, thanks¡